# Having difficulties with Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: liquid, jekyll

I'm tring to do a loop for Nav links below my posts. This is going into the _layout of posts.html

I can't get the link to not show if the post is the last or the first. Any help would be awesome.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}

    {% if post.previous != forloop.last %} 
        ← Last
    {% elsif post.next != forloop.first %} 
        Next →
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had better luck using page.next/previous

```
    {% if page.previous %} 
        <a rel="prev" href="{{ page.previous.url }}">&larr; Older</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if page.next %} 
        <a rel="next" href="{{ page.next.url }}">Newer &rarr;</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` statements to just check if `post.previous` exists.

```
{% if post.previous %}
<span class="page-nav-item">
    <a rel="prev" href="{{ post.previous.url }}" title="View {{ post.previous.title }}">&larr; View previous article</a>
</span>
{% endif %}
{% if post.next %}
<span class="page-nav-item">
    <a rel="next" href="{{ post.next.url }}" title="View {{ post.next.title }}">View next article &rarr;</a>
</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I had better luck using 'page.next' and 'page.previous', but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add images to your link background.
 For images to show up just add `image: [image location]` in your YAML front matter

```
<div class="postNav clearfix">
    {% if page.previous.url %} 
      <a class="prev{% if page.previous.image %} image{% endif %}" href="{{ page.previous.url }}"><span>&laquo;&nbsp;{{ page.previous.title }}</span>
      {% if page.previous.image %} 
        <img src="{{ '/assets/blog-img/' |  append: page.previous.image }}" alt="">
      {% endif %}
    </a>
    {% endif %}  
    {% if page.next.url %}  
      <a class="next{% if page.next.image %} image{% endif %}" href="{{ page.next.url }}"><span>{{ page.next.title }}&nbsp;&raquo;</span>
      {% if page.next.image %} 
        <img src="{{ '/assets/blog-img/' | append: page.next.image }}" alt="">
      {% endif %} 
      </a>
        {% endif %}
 </div>
```